# how will i search a record inside a textfile formatted like database table in java?

Tags: java, text-files

is there any possibilities of querying a data or set of record in a textfile like for example i have a text file that contains:

```
client_id  l_name  f_name   address
     0001  marcus  Sy       somewhere
     0002  John    Michael  overthere
```

In my java gui, i have a clientIdField(jtextfield) where i will input the client_id, then clicking a button to delete that record where the client_id is equal to my textfile client_id. Is that possible? I also have a database and it works really good, i just wanna try it in text file because im studying file handlings in java.

What i want is that if i will input 0001 then marcus Sy somwhere will come out to where i wanted them to be displayed, let's say a text area.

Comment: Is it a .tsv-File (http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/text/tab-separated-values)?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Read the file as  List<Client> in memory, and write the list back to the file when you want to save the changes.

Comment: Thanks @JBNizet , do u have any links or tutorials for that?

Comment: @PeterRader its a .txt file, before i do search i use file chooser to select the text file and get its file name and there will i implement the search. kinda.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/charstreams.html